# Как можно кэшировать поисковые запросы к API фотобанков?

Tags: php

Во всех фотобанках имеющих API есть **лимиты по запросам в час**, и многие предлагают кэшировать запросы у себя **на сервере при помощи PHP**, чтобы не выходить из лимитов. 
Возник вопрос, каждый человек будет вбивать практически ***уникальный запрос*** в поиск, используя разные слова, и тогда получается смысл всего кэширования в PHP пропадает. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить в этом случае и как реализовать действительно нормальное кэширование запросов к API фотобанков на PHP?

Comment: кэшируйте популярные. либо предугадывайте желания пользователя и по мере набора поискового запроса предлагайте ему варианты, которые у вас будут закешированы, что бы он не свой уникальный запрос написал, а выбрал из предложенных

Comment: спасибо за совет! Идея хорошая!